# syntax error near unexpected token `else' how to resolve

Tags: bash, shell, sh

i'm trying to figure out what's wrong with this script:

```
  1 #! /bin/sh
  2
  3 METH1=$(ip=$(ifconfig eth0 | awk '$1 == "inet" {print $2}'):7001; echo $ip)
  4 METH2=$(echo $(find /u01/ -name config.xml |grep -v bak| xargs grep -A4 AdminServer | grep listen-address | cut -d'>' -f 2 | cut -d'<' -f 1))
  5
  6 PATH=$(find /u01/oracle/config/ -wholename */AdminServer)
  7
  8 if [ "$PATH" ] = 0; then
  9         if [ "$METH1" ] = 0; then
 10                 echo $METH1
 11         elif [ "$METH2" ] = 0
 12                 echo $METH2
 13         else
 14                 exit()
 15 else
 16         if [ "$METH2" ] = 0; then
 17                 echo $METH2
 18         else
 19                 exit()
 20 fi
```

which generates this error:

```
./adminurl.sh: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./adminurl.sh: line 13: `       else'
```

Any help is apreciated.

Comment: remove `=0` (outside `[ ..]`) and add `then` after `elif [ "$METH2" ] = 0`.

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: As an aside, the command substitution nesting is not necessary. `METH1=$(ip=$(command):7001; echo $ip)` is the same as `METH1=$(command):7001` (which also avoids unquoted expansion), and `METH2=$(echo $(command))` is the same as `METH2=$(command)`.

Comment: Further, don't use `PATH` as a variable name. It's a reserved shell variable, and resetting it breaks things. In general, prefer lowercase names for your own variables.

Comment: The `[ ... ] = 0` condition won't work to check for successful exit status. Use just `if [ ... ]; then` for that.

Comment: You're also confusing different kinds of results from commands. `var=$(command)` stores the *output* from the command, not its exit status  (success/failure). The exit status is available as `$?` immediately after the command, but only until some other command (*any* other command) executes and replaced that status. Also, the exit status of a compound command is the status of its last command; in both of your cases, that'd be `echo`, which almost certainly succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

After "elif" statement you need an other "then" keyword

line 11 :

```
elif [ "$METH2" ] = 0
then 
    echo $METH2
```

Comment: checked. now i've "./adminurl.sh: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `else'". It refers to line 15 of the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a couple of things in your `if-elif-else` statements. The first thing to note is that after every `elif`, you need a `then`. After that, your interior if-else statements need to be closed with their own `fi`. Lastly, remove the parentheses from the calls to exit, they are not needed.

Your code would look as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

METH1=$(ip=$(ifconfig eth0 | awk '$1 == "inet" {print $2}'):7001; echo $ip)
METH2=$(echo $(find /u01/ -name config.xml |grep -v bak| xargs grep -A4 AdminServer | grep listen-address | cut -d'>' -f 2 | cut -d'<' -f 1))

PATH=$(find /u01/oracle/config/ -wholename */AdminServer)

if [ "$PATH" ] = 0; then
  if [ "$METH1" ] = 0; then
     echo $METH1
  elif [ "$METH2" ] = 0; then
     echo $METH2
  else
    exit
  fi
else
  if [ "$METH2" ] = 0; then
    echo $METH2
  else
    exit
  fi
fi
```

*Note:* You're also using sh instead of bash. If you do want to use bash, consider changing the hashbang line from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, note that the expression "=0" is intended as a success exit code "0". In your case, putting the 0 into the brakets means the variable must return 0 as integer. Indeed the error i've got is "line 8 and 17: integer expression expected".

Comment: the if statemets are meaning: "if the execution of the command in the variable return 0 then echo its content.

Comment: Ah I see, okay I will update the answer to reflect the behavior of the `= 0` to what you had previously.

Comment: @FrancescoRenzi edited now. Sorry about that, I was unfamiliar with that syntax. Let me know if it is working now.

Comment: in line 8 and 17 close brakets are missing: "line 8 and 17: [: missing `]'" even if there are correctly after space. This is quite strange...